# Can I have two File Managers installed in Xubuntu 16.04.5 with no confilcts?

Tags: xubuntu, thunar, nemo

I have Thunar 1.6 as my default file manager, can I install Nemo as my second file manager? I have doubts of installing Nemo and get conflicts between each other. If it is possible should I change some settings in Xubuntu to run it smoothly ? Thanks, Vladi

Comment: I have installed Nautilus, Nemo and Dolphin in addition to the default Caja on Ubuntu 18.04 Mate, with no conflicts. Each has its own independent add-ons. I still allow Caja to manage the desktop, but for file management I use whichever suits me. It would be necessary to change settings in order to use a different handler, but I have not had to do this, since I am content with Caja as the desktop manager. I had similar multiple file managers on 16.04.

Comment: @AFH Ok, I'll install Nemo, thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple file managers installed , and even run different ones simultaneously, in Ubuntu 16.04 (and 18.04, as well). Currently, I have Doiuble Commander, Nautilus and Dolphin installed on the machine from which I'm typing (I like the split view some offer). Hopefully, that should also work in Xubuntu.

[image: Multiple file managers in Ubuntu]

Comment: good to know that I can Install a second File Manager. thks.